# Json encode displays numbers instead of letters

Tags: php, json

Please help, I tried everything. I getting data from my database that is utf8_bin and displaying in php, but when i put characters like ć,č,ž,š Json displays numbers instead.I already tried mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET 'utf8'"); but nothing.  my Json code is :

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();
$sviArray = array();
$responseZagreb=array();
// include db connect class
require_once('DB_connect.php');

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_connect();

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET 'utf8'");

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM Istra") or die(mysql_error());
 $resultZagreb = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM Zagreb") or die(mysql_error());


$place=array();



// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["Istra"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["id"] = $row["ID"];
        $product["datum"] = $row["DATUM"];
        $product["grad"] = $row["GRAD"];
        $product["place"] = $row["PLACE"];
        $product["adresa"] = $row["ADRESA"];
        $product["Dogadaj"]=$row["DOGADAJ"];
        $product["Cijena"]=$row["CIJENA"];
        $product["Slika"]=$row["SLIKA"];
        $product["Tip"]=$row["TIP"];

$place=$row['PLACE'];
$result0 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(ocjena) AS value_sum FROM Ocjena where place='$place'"); 
$cijena=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(cijena) AS values_cijena FROM Ocjena where place='$place'");
$cijenacount=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(cijena) AS cijena_count FROM Ocjena where place='$place'");
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ocjena) AS value_sum1 FROM Ocjena where place='$place'");
$row0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result0); 
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

$row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($cijena); 
$row3=mysql_fetch_assoc($cijenacount);

$sum0 = $row0['value_sum'];
$sum1 = $row1['value_sum1'];

$sum2=$row2['values_cijena'];
$sum3=$row3['cijena_count'];


if($sum1!=0){
$rez=$sum0/$sum1;
 }
else $rez=0;
$product["Ocjena"]=$rez;

if($sum2!=0){

$rezCijena=$sum2/$sum3;
}
else $rezCijena=0;

$product["cijena"]=$rezCijena;

        // push single product into final response array
         array_push($response["Istra"], $product);
    }






    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $responseZagreb["Zagreb"] = array();

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultZagreb)) 
    {
        // temp user array
        $productZagreb = array();
        $productZagreb["id"] = $row1["ID"];
        $productZagreb["datum"] = $row1["DATUM"];
        $productZagreb["grad"] = $row1["GRAD"];
        $productZagreb["place"] = $row1["PLACE"];
        $productZagreb["adresa"] = $row1["ADRESA"];
        $productZagreb["Dogadaj"]=$row1["DOGADAJ"];
        $productZagreb["Cijena"]=$row1["CIJENA"];
        $productZagreb["Slika"]=$row1["SLIKA"];
        $productZagreb["Tip"]=$row["TIP"];

       $place=$row['PLACE'];
$result0 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(ocjena) AS value_sum FROM Ocjena where place='$place'"); 

$result1=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ocjena) AS value_sum1 FROM Ocjena where place='$place'");
$row0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result0); 
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

$sum0 = $row0['value_sum'];
$sum1 = $row1['value_sum1'];

if($sum1!=0){
$rez=$sum0/$sum1;

}

 $productZagreb["Ocjena"]=$rez;






        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($responseZagreb["Zagreb"], $productZagreb);
    }



    // looping through all results
    // products node

$sviArray=array_merge($responseZagreb,$response);



 // echoing JSON response
   echo stripcslashes(json_encode ($sviArray));



}
 else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) option.

```
echo stripcslashes(json_encode ($sviArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```